# CString to UTF8 conversion fails for "ý"

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, cstring

In my application I want to convert a string that contains character ý, to UTF-8. But its not giving the exact result.
I am using WideCharToMultiByte function, it is converting the purticular character to Ã½.

For Example : 
Input - "ý"
Output - "Ã½"

Please see the code below..

```
String strBuffer("ý" );
char *utf8Buffer = (char*)malloc(strBuffer.GetLength()+1);
int utf8bufferLength = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, (LPCWSTR)strBuffer.GetBuffer(strBuffer.GetLength() + 1)),
 strBuffer.GetLength(), utf8Buffer, strBuffer.GetLength() * 4,0,0);
```

Please give your suggestions...

- Binoy Krishna

Comment: Congratulations, it works.  Your debugger has no idea that your char* contains utf8 encoded text, you have to let it know.  Use the s8 format specifier.

Answer (score 1):

Unicode codepoint for *letter* **ý**, according to [this page](http://unicode-table.com/en/00FD/) is 253<sub>10</sub> or FD<sub>16</sub>. UTF-8 representation is 195 189 decimal or C3 BD hexadecimal. These two *bytes* can be seen as *letters* **Ã½** in your program and/or debugger, but they are UTF-8 numbers, so they are *bytes*, not *letters*.

In another words the output and <strike>the code</strike> are fine, and your expectations are wrong. I can't say why are they wrong because you haven't mentioned what exactly were you expecting.

EDIT: The code should be improved. See Rudolfs' answer for more info.

Answer (score 0):

While I was writing this an answer explaining the character values you are seeing was already posted, however, there are two things to mention about your code:

1) you should use the `_T()` macro when initializing the string: `CString strBuffer(_T("ý"));` The `_T()` macro is defined in `tchar.h` and maps to the correct string type depending on the value of the `_UNICODE` macro.

2) do not use the `GetLength()` to calculate the size of the UTF-8 buffer, see the documentation of [WideCharToMultiByte](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374130%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in MSDN, it shows how to use the function to calculate the needed length for the UTF-8 buffer in the comments section.

Here is a small example that verifies the output according to the codepoints and demonstrates how to use the automatic length calculation:

```
#define _AFXDLL
#include <afx.h>

#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    CString wideStrBuffer(_T("ý"));
    // The length calculation assumes wideStrBuffer is zero terminated
    CStringA utf8Buffer('\0', WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, wideStrBuffer.GetBuffer(), -1, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL));
    WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, wideStrBuffer.GetBuffer(), -1, utf8Buffer.GetBuffer(), utf8Buffer.GetLength(), NULL, NULL);
    if (static_cast<unsigned char>(utf8Buffer[0]) == 195 && static_cast<unsigned char>(utf8Buffer[1]) == 189)
    {
        std::cout << "Conversion successful!" << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```